# Remove first byte from NSMutableData

Tags: iphone, nsdata

```
NSMutableData *requestData = (NSMutableData*)[request responseData];
```

returns

"[{JSON_STRING}]"

so I want to strip out the "[" / "]" without converting to NSString and then back to NSData. The easiest way to do this is to strip out the first and last byte.

`[requestData setLength:[requestData length]-1];` removes the last byte.

How to remove the first byte? I tried the solution below, but doesn't work..

```
NSRange range = {0, 1};
[requestData resetBytesInRange:range];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(1, [requestData length] - 2);
NSData *refinedData = [requestData subdataWithRange:range];
```

This should take care of both the first and last character.

Answer (score 11):

Here's how you strip the first byte off an NSMutableData:

```
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
[requestData replaceBytesInRange:range withBytes:NULL length:0];
```

Comment: This is better than `[data subdataWithRange:]` because in this case no data copying happens.

Comment: ... and in Swift it would be `data.replaceBytesInRange(range, withBytes:nil, length:0)`

Comment: ok, but what does this change, the alloced size remains the same